# Crypto in Nodejs and Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, cryptography, node-crypto

I want crypto a string and pass to Rails app,so I find the crypto  library both in Nodejs and Ruby.

In Nodejs:

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr',
    password = 'd6F3Efeqd6F3Efeqd6F3Efeqd6F3Efeq';

function encrypt(text){
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm,password)
  var crypted = cipher.update(text,'ascii',"base64")
  crypted += cipher.final("base64");
  return crypted;
}
```

The result is :

```
encrypt("1") //-输出 2g==
```

In Ruby

```
def encrypt(des_text)
    des = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-256-ctr')
    des.encrypt
    des.key = 'd6F3Efeqd6F3Efeqd6F3Efeqd6F3Efeq'
    result = des.update(des_text)
    result << des.final
    return Base64.encode64 result
end
```

The result is :

```
encrypt("1")  # 输出 1A==
```

So I use the same way and key to crypto  a same string,Why the result is not the same?

Comment: What are the encrypted bytes before you base64-encode them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference between crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password) and crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv) is that password is used to derive key and IV.

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr',
    key = 'd6F3Efeqd6F3Efeqd6F3Efeqd6F3Efeq',
    iv = "1234567890123456";

function encrypt(text){
  var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm,key,iv)
  var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf-8',"base64")
  crypted += cipher.final("base64");
  return crypted;
}

console.log(encrypt("1")); // return bQ==
```

In Ruby, if you haven't specify iv then it will use a default iv.

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

def encrypt(des_text)
    des = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-256-ctr')
    des.encrypt
    des.key = 'd6F3Efeqd6F3Efeqd6F3Efeqd6F3Efeq'
    des.iv = "1234567890123456"
    result = des.update(des_text)
    result << des.final
    return Base64.encode64 result
end

p encrypt("1").strip # return bQ==
```